# ellipses with various angles and eccentricities in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a plot with ellipses as markers. Here is a sample code making one large ellipse that for now is actually a circle.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.2
import numpy as np
import pylab
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

PlotFileName="test.pdf"
pdf = PdfPages(PlotFileName)
fig=plt.figure(1)
ax1=fig.add_subplot(111)
x_lim=3
plt.xlim([0,x_lim])
plt.ylim([0,x_lim])

F=pylab.gcf()
DefSize = F.get_size_inches()

#These lines have a true angle of 45 degrees, only as a reference:
offset_along_x=x_lim-(x_lim/ax_ratio)
ax1.plot([offset_along_x/2, x_lim-(offset_along_x/2)], [0, x_lim], "b")
ax1.plot([offset_along_x/2, x_lim-(offset_along_x/2)], [x_lim, 0], "b")

e=0.0
theta=0
maj_ax=2
min_ax=maj_ax*np.sqrt(1-e**2)
xconst=(DefSize[1]/DefSize[0])*np.cos(theta*np.pi/180)-np.sin(theta*np.pi/180)
yconst=np.cos(theta*np.pi/180)+(DefSize[1]/DefSize[0])*np.sin(theta*np.pi/180)
print("xconstant= {}".format(xconst))
print("yconstant= {}".format(yconst))
ax1.add_artist(Ellipse((x_lim/2, x_lim/2), xconst*maj_ax, yconst*min_ax, angle=theta, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black",zorder=2, alpha=0.5))

pdf.savefig(fig)
pdf.close()
plt.close()
```

Although in this simplified case, `ax1.axis("equal")` will give a pure circle, but in my final plot, this command will ruin the whole plot (the scales aren't equal). So I want to make a general purpose ellipse tool without using `ax1.axis("equal")`. As you see, you can set the eccentricity and the inclination angle of the major axis in this program.

**The problem:**
The problem seems to be that I don't understand how matplotlib rotates its images. If you change the value of `theta` here to a value other than 0 or 90, the object will no longer be a circle. with `ax1.axis("equal")` the output is a circle now matter what the value of `theta` is. So my first problem is this: what should I do to keep the output as a circle while changing `theta`. I assume that once I fix this, it will also work for an ellipse. Could someone please help me with this? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I'v noticed that there exists [Circle](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html#matplotlib.patches.Circle) in the patches, why don't you just use it instead of Ellipse?

Comment: I want to make an ellipse finally. I am making a circle now to calibrate my program. If it works correctly with a circle, it will work with an ellipse.

Comment: I think you're just confused on data coordinates vs display coordinates.  Currently the ellipse is being plotted in _data_ coordinates.  You seem to want the rotation, width, and height in _display_ coordinates, but the center in data coordinates, correct?  If so, you just need to define the correct transform.  I'm traveling right now, so I can't give an example, but this tutorial is a good start: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/transforms_tutorial.html You'll want a blended transform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In matplotlib the eclipse position and form is set by first scaling to the height and width then rotating around it's center and then translating to the required position. So rotating and scaling the height and with before may mork (like in your script), but is hard to get exactly right (you probably have to scale and invert the rotation, but my transformation math is rusty).

If you want to scale the ellipse's form correctly you'll need to subclass the Ellipse class and redefine the `_recompute_transform` function:

```
from matplotlib import transforms

class TransformedEllipse(Ellipse):

    def __init__(self, xy, width, height, angle=0.0, fix_x = 1.0, **kwargs):
        Ellipse.__init__(self, xy, width, height, angle, **kwargs)

        self.fix_x = fix_x

    def _recompute_transform(self):

        center = (self.convert_xunits(self.center[0]),
                  self.convert_yunits(self.center[1]))
        width = self.convert_xunits(self.width)
        height = self.convert_yunits(self.height)
        self._patch_transform = transforms.Affine2D() \
            .scale(width * 0.5, height * 0.5) \
            .rotate_deg(self.angle) \
            .scale(self.fix_x, 1) \
            .translate(*center)
```

and use it like so:

```
fix_x = DefSize[1]/DefSize[0]/ax_ratio

ellipse = TransformedEllipse((x_lim/2.0, x_lim/2.0), maj_ax, min_ax, angle=theta, facecolor="green", edgecolor="black",zorder=2, alpha=0.5, fix_x = fix_x)
```

P.S. I assume the `ax_ratio` to be `y_lim / x_lim`!

Comment: In copying the code here I forgot to add `ax_ratio==DefSize[0]/DefSize[1]`. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you so much arjenve, it worked perfectly with this new class you defined. It works perfectly. Thanks again.